# how to set Lineseries point template in code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, telerik

Basically i would like to apply this XAML code in the C# behind. Here is the XAML

```
        <telerik:LineSeries Stroke="Transparent">
            <telerik:LineSeries.PointTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Fill="DarkGreen" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </telerik:LineSeries.PointTemplate>
        </telerik:LineSeries>
```

This is what i have tried:

```
Ellipse e = new Ellipse();
LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
e.Height = 10; 
e.Width = 10; 
line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
line.PointTemplate = new DataTemplate(e);
```

But it doesn't work i get a "Value for DataTemplate.DataType must be of the type System.Type." error. Anybody know how to correctly translate the XAML above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I do, I create a Resource:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PointTemplate">
        <Ellipse Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Coral"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then you would apply it by doing:

```
line.PointTemplate = this.Resources["PointTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
```

Comment: Would this work even if the radcartesianchart that i create is created in the c#?

Comment: If you add the XML and use that code in your codebehind, it will work. You have to make sure your are doing `radCartesianChart.Series.Add(line);` to add the line to your chart.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML create a static Resource and assign it to PointTemplate Property

```
<Window.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="PointTemplate">
<Ellipse Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Coral"/>
</DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<telerik:ChartSeriesDescriptor.Style>
<Style TargetType="telerik:ScatterSplineSeries">
<Setter Property="YValueBinding" Value="YValue" />
<Setter Property="XValueBinding" Value="XValue" />
<Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2" />
<Setter Property="PointTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PointTemplate}"  />
</Style>
</telerik:ChartSeriesDescriptor.Style>`
```